# Что то типа слайдера/навигационного меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Доброе всем. Подскажите пожалуйста, как на JS реализовать что то типа слайдера, только это навигационное меню, т.е при клике на нижнюю кнопку (на картинке ниже), эти 3 блока должны уезжать и должны появляться другие блоки, 6 штук (в 2 раза меньше). Ну и при втором клике должны снова появляться эти 3 блока, что то типа слайдера, только хочу сам написать, с вашей помощью, и что бы была кнопка снизу, JS знаю, но практики мало, не знаю как реализовать, в какую сторону копать хотя бы.. заранее спасибо!
[image: слайдер]

Comment: Почитайте вот эту статейку (https://webformyself.com/kak-sdelat-prostoj-slajder-na-javascript-bez-jquery/). Там много информации по всей теме слайдеров. Попробуйте реализовать все примеры сами и потом вы получите базовые знания для того что бы продвигаться по этой теме дальше.

Comment: Годно, спс, для практики пойдет, только вот я думаю мне нужен вариант с позиционированием слайдов, а не с затуханием (opacity) вот нашел статью на хабре, по описанию вроде подходит: https://habrahabr.ru/post/319394/

Comment: Это все работает одинаково. По ходу практики вы поймете как это устроено и дальше вопрос будет уже не в том как реализовать как в том что бы сделать.